# Find an euler cycle using the PairViz package in R (v 3.0.2)

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to find an euler cycle (a cycle that visits all the edges in a graph exactly once) using the [PairViz](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PairViz/PairViz.pdf) package in R. The edges of my graph are as below:

> 1 -> 10 
>  2 -> 1,6
>  3 -> 2
>  4 -> 2
>  5 -> 4
>  6 ->
>   5,8
>  7 -> 9
>  8 -> 7
>  9 -> 6
>  10 -> 3

There is an euler cycle here:

> 6->8->7->9->6->5->4->2->1->10->3->2->6

In R, firstly I created a graph, g, using the ['graph'](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html) package from bioconductor.

```
g <- new("graphNEL", nodes=as.character(1:10), edgemode="directed")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="1", to="10")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="2", to="1")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="2", to="6")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="3", to="2")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="4", to="2")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="5", to="4")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="6", to="5")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="6", to="8")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="7", to="9")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="8", to="7")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="9", to="6")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="10", to="3")
```

Then I use the eulerian() function from the PairViz package.

```
ecycle <- eulerian(g, weighted=F)
```

Here, I get the following exception:

```
the graph is undirected and the following edges are not reciprocated:
 ‘1|2’, ‘6|2’, ‘2|3’, ‘2|4’, ‘4|5’, ‘5|6’, ‘8|6’, ‘9|7’, ‘7|8’, ‘6|9’, ‘3|10’ 

Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “graphNEL” object: FALSE
```

The traceback() shows the following:

```
14: stop(msg, " ", errors, domain = NA)
13: validObject(.Object)
12: .local(.Object, ...)
11: initialize(value, ...)
10: initialize(value, ...)
9: new("graphNEL", nodes = n, edgeL = ed)
8: mk_even_graph(self, weighted = weighted)
7: mk_even_graph(self, weighted = weighted)
6: eulerian(g, weighted = F)
5: eulerian(g, weighted = F) at .active-rstudio-document#14
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("~/.active-rstudio-document")
```

However, the same approach works for finding an euler path from a complete digraph (code given below).

```
g <- new("graphNEL", nodes=c("a","b","c", "d"), edgemode="directed")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="a", to="b")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="a", to="c")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="a", to="d")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="b", to="c")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="b", to="d")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="b", to="a")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="c", to="d")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="c", to="a")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="c", to="b")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="d", to="a")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="d", to="b")
g <- addEdge(graph=g, from="d", to="c")
eulerian(g, weighted=F)
```

I understand that the euler path and the euler cycle are not same, and the eulerian() function return an euler path. However, as there is an euler cycle in my graph, there must be an euler path (at least) there, and that should be returned.

Please help me if I am making any mistake. I would also appreciate if you can suggest me any other package or any other solution.

Note: I am running this code from RStudio (v0.98.501) in windows 7 (64 bit).

Thanks in advance.

Ashis.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the algorithm to find an euler cycle from a balanced (for every node, indegree=outdegree) directed graph. All the nodes have to be connected. The code is given below:

```
eulerCycle <- function(g, start=NULL){
  eulerCycle <- c()
  curNode <- ifelse(is.null(start), nodes(g)[1], start)

  while(!is.na(curNode)){
    cycle <- curNode
    while(!is.na(nextNode <- randomWalkNext(g, curNode))){
      g <- removeEdge(graph=g, from=curNode, to=nextNode)
      cycle <- append(cycle, nextNode)
      curNode <- nextNode
    }

    if(length(eulerCycle)==0){
      eulerCycle <- cycle
    }
    else{
      insertIndex <- which(eulerCycle==cycle[1])[1]
      eulerCycle <- append(eulerCycle,after=insertIndex,values=cycle[-1])
    }

    curNode <- getAnUnexploredNode(g, nodes=eulerCycle)
  }

  return(eulerCycle)
}

getAnUnexploredNode <- function(g, nodes){
  degrees <- degree(g, Nodes=nodes)
  nodeIndexes <- which(degrees$outDegree+degrees$inDegree>0)
  node <- NA
  if(length(nodeIndexes)>0){
    node <- nodes[nodeIndexes[1]]
  }
  return(node)
}

randomWalkNext <- function(g, from){
  outEdges <- edges(object=g, which=from)[[1]]
  nextNode <- NA
  if(length(outEdges)>0){
    nextNode <- outEdges[1]
  }
  return(nextNode)
}
```

When I run the following code with the graph of my interest,

```
ec <- eulerCycle(g, start="6")
print(ec)
```

I get the following output.

```
[1] "6"  "5"  "4"  "2"  "1"  "10" "3"  "2"  "6"  "8"  "7"  "9"  "6"
```

Hope this would come to help to others.

Comment: Yes it does... My code works fine for short runs... but not as good for the original test. I am trying to learn from your code but it is a little hard to understand some parts. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that PairViz's `eulerian` function will only act on even graphs (that is, graphs for which every node is even). See documentation at http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/PairViz/docs/eulerian for more details, noting that `mk_euler_graph` is (I think) a typo for `mk_even_graph`.

To see this in R, try this after creating your graph:

```
etour(g)
```

and you'll be told:

```
Error in etour(g) : Graph must be an even graph.
```

If you make your graph undirected by changing the first line of your code to this:

```
g <- new("graphNEL", nodes=as.character(1:10), edgemode="undirected")
```

then you'll produce this:

```
> g
A graphNEL graph with undirected edges
Number of Nodes = 10 
Number of Edges = 12 
> ecycle <- eulerian(g, weighted=F)
> ecycle
 [1] "1"  "10" "3"  "2"  "6"  "8"  "7"  "9"  "6"  "5"  "4"  "2"  "1" 
>
```

which is the Euler cycle for the undirected version of your graph.

As far as I know, though, there's no way to apply the `eulerian` function to directed graphs like this.

Comment: In fact, I need to find an euler cycle in a directed graph. Finding no other alternatives, I am now implementing it. Thank you, Neil, for your response.